# Confusion in finding follow of Gammar

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, grammar

I have confusion in finding follow of Grammar

**S->(L)|a**
**L->L,S|S**

Follow(L)={$ ,} or Follow(L)= {$}
Which one is right and why ?

Comment: Please check the answer posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are incorrect.

```
FOLLOW(A) of non-terminal A is the set of terminal symbols 
that can follow in the derivation sequence
```

FOLLOW(L), check where it appears in the right hand side of productions. It is there in

```
             S->(L)
```

when this production is considered for derivation, what follows L is ).

```
            L->L,S
```

similarly, when this production is considered for derivation, what follows L is ,.

```
           FOLLOW(L) = {),,}
```